# HTML table output with PHP for loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am having trouble with my table as I run it through the for loop. Currently I am getting the following output:

> ```
> Room(s)   Check-In    Check-Out   No. of Nights   Rate
>
> Room1 04-09-2014  05-09-2014  1   $0
>
> Room2 04-09-2014  05-09-2014  1   $0
>
> Room3 04-09-2014  05-09-2014  1   $100.00
>
> Room4 04-09-2014  05-09-2014  1   $100.00
> ```

What I want it to look like is this:

> ```
> Room(s)   Check-In    Check-Out   No. of Nights   Rate
>
> Room3 04-09-2014  05-09-2014  1   $100.00
>
> Room4 04-09-2014  05-09-2014  1   $100.00
> ```

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 100.00
    [4] => 100.00
)
```

I want anything with an array value of 0 to be omitted but if I change the value of 'X' I get one too few or one too many rows.

The 0 values are generated from checkbox posts `<input type="hidden" name="chk" value="0">` and not from the SQL statement.

I have tried: `if ($_SESSION['r_id'][$x] != 0)` it gives:

> ```
> Room(s)   Check-In    Check-Out   No. of Nights   Rate
>
> Room1 04-09-2014  05-09-2014  1   $100.00  <-- Should be Room3
>
> Room2 04-09-2014  05-09-2014  1   $100.00  <-- Should be Room4
> ```

**HTML/SQL/PHP:**

```
   <table width="500" border="0" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td>Room(s)</td>
                <td>Check-In</td>
                <td>Check-Out</td>
                <td>No. of Nights</td>
                <td>Rate</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <?

                $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM room");
                $sth->execute();
                $result = $sth->fetchAll();

                $y = 0;
                for ($x=1; $x<=count($_SESSION['r_id']); $x++) { 

                ?>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- Modal Content -->
                    <div id="r_id_<?=$y?>" class="reveal-modal">
                         <h1><?=$result[$y]['r_type'];?></h1> 
                         <p><?=$result[$y]['r_desc'];?></p>
                         <h2>$<?=$result[$y]['r_rate'];?></h2> 
                         <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
                    </div><!-- Modal Content End -->

                    <!-- Modal Link -->
                    <a href="#" data-reveal-id="r_id_<?=$y?>"><?=$result[$y]['r_type'];?></a>
                    <!-- Modal Link End --></td>

                <td><?=$_SESSION['checkin_date'];?></td>
                <td><?=$_SESSION['checkout_date'];?></td>
                <td><?=$_SESSION['no_nights'];?></td>
                <td>$<?=$_SESSION['r_id'][$x];?></td>
              </tr>
              <?
              $y++;
              }       
              ?>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to remove an element in the array having a specific value you can do like,

Having this array:

```
$arr = array('0', '0', '100.00', '100.00');
```

You can do:

```
$arr = array_diff($arr, array('0'));
```

And the value of $arr will be:

```
array('100.00', '100.00')
```

**Edit:**

As per the  result, your `$y` is not getting incremented. Close your `if` before `$y++`. Check if below works.

```
<?php
  $y = 0;
  for ($x=1; $x<=count($_SESSION['r_id']); $x++) {

  if($_SESSION['r_id'][$x] != 0)
  {
?>

<tr>
    <td>
       <!-- Modal Content -->
       <div id="r_id_<?=$y?>" class="reveal-modal">
           <h1><?=$result[$y]['r_type'];?></h1> 
           <p><?=$result[$y]['r_desc'];?></p>
           <h2>$<?=$result[$y]['r_rate'];?></h2> 
           <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
       </div>
       <!-- Modal Content End -->

       <!-- Modal Link -->
       <a href="#" data-reveal-id="r_id_<?=$y?>"><?=$result[$y]['r_type'];?></a>
       <!-- Modal Link End -->
    </td>

    <td><?=$_SESSION['checkin_date'];?></td>
    <td><?=$_SESSION['checkout_date'];?></td>
    <td><?=$_SESSION['no_nights'];?></td>
    <td>$<?=$_SESSION['r_id'][$x];?></td>
</tr>

<?php
    }
    $y++;
  }       
?>
```

Comment: I have tried different variations of subtracting 0's from the array. When I remove the 0 values, all columns except the first column become correct (see example above). Room1 and Room2 are shown instead of Room3 and Room4.

Comment: array(4) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "100.00"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "100.00"
}

Answer (score 0):

You could update your SQL statement to only select results where the price is not 0. Something like this:

`SELECT * FROM room WHERE rate NOT IN (0)`

Or as @andrew suggested, just choose greater than:

`SELECT * FROM room WHERE rate > 0`

Comment: wouldn't be faster if you did rate>0? Since the items are hotel rates, i don't think it will be possible to have rate<0.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, the zeros are generated from checkboxes `<input type="hidden" name="chk" value="0">` not from the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$RoomAvail=array("0","0","0","100","100");
$zeroValue="0";
$_SESSION['r_id']=array_diff($messages, [$del_val]); //Its avoid zero value
```

then u do each instead loop